# Can StructuredFormatDisplayAttribute be used as part of an extension method

Tags: f#, formatting, type-extension

I dont think its possible but can you do something similar to this to allow custom formatting via a Type extension?

```
[<StructuredFormatDisplayAttribute("Rate: {PrettyPrinter}")>]
type Rate with 
    member x.PrettyPrinter = x.Title + string x.Value
```

*Note: It looks to be possible as an intrinsic extension(Same assembly) but not as an optional extension*.

If not I guess this could be a feature request, unless anyone has a nice alternative?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. In FSI, you can use [`fsi.AddPrinter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee842576.aspx) to customize output.

```ml
fsi.AddPrinter (fun (x: Rate) -> x.Title + string x.Value)
```

EDIT

For general string formatting, you can use `Printf` with the `%a` format specifier. A few extra functions can make this more convenient.

```ml
[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module Rate =
  let stringify (x: Rate) = x.Title + string x.Value
  let print rate = printf "%s" (stringify rate)

printf "Rate: %a" (fun _ -> Rate.print) rate
let formattedString = sprintf "Rate: %a" (fun _ -> Rate.stringify) rate
```

Comment: Pity a printer cannot be added to the standard console.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can send anything you want to stdout. There is no _default display_ of types in that context.

Comment: I meant it would be nice to extend the std printer too.  Printf.AddPrinter (fun (x: Rate) -> x.Title + string x.Value)

Comment: @7sharp9: I included in my answer one way to do this with `Printf`.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, there `StructuredFormatDisplayAttribute` works only for members that are compiled as properties (that includes standard properties, same assembly extensions, but not extension members). Under the cover, it is accessed using reflection (as you see, it can be private too):

```
let getProperty (obj: obj) name =
    let ty = obj.GetType()
    ty.InvokeMember(name, (BindingFlags.GetProperty ||| BindingFlags.Instance ||| 
        BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic), 
        null, obj, [| |],CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If you need this for debugging purposes, then the `DebuggerTypeProxy` attribute might be an alternative (see [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8eyd8zc.aspx)). This allows you to replace the original type with a proxy type that is used for showing the type in a debugger. (But I think the attribute still has to be placed on the actual type definition and not on an extension.)

Comment: This wasn't for debugging just for normal console output. I checked and the attribute has to be placed on the actual type definition although the actual pretty printing code can be placed in an extension and also in a module.